# cv::VideoWriter isn't saving any video

Tags: c++, opencv, ros, video-recording

I'm trying to get cv::VideoWriter to work but I'm having trouble.

```
if (recording)
{
    vid.write(imagecl);
    std::cout << "\trecording..." << std::endl;
}
        
cv::imshow(CAMERA_TOPIC, imagecl);
rec_key = cv::waitKey(1);
imagecl.release();

if (rec_key == 114 && !recording)
{
    std::cout << "\t\tStarted Recording" << std::endl;
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    now_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
    vidname = VIDEO_PATH + date_str(std::ctime(&now_time)) + ".mp4";
    std::cout << "\tSaving video to -> " << vidname << std::endl; 
    codec = cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('a','v','c','1');
    vid = cv::VideoWriter(vidname, codec, 30, cv::Size(frame_width, frame_height), true);
    recording = true;
}   
else if (rec_key == 115 && recording)
{   
    std::cout << "\t\tEnded recording" << std::endl;
    vid.release();
    recording = false;
}
```

This code is part of a video_recorder function what is executing inside an infinite loop. I'm using another thread to fill the imagecl with the frames I want to record. The cv::imshow is working properly (it opens a window and displays the frames), but I can't get to save videos with cv::VideoWriter. The 'r' and 's' keys are triggering the conditions as I get the terminal messages of "started recording" and then "recording" each loop and then "ended recording". I double checked the path and it is correct. I'm saving to "/home/username/videoname.mp4". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check frame sizes are equal to what you promised in the VideoWriter constructor

Comment: Does your application have permissions to write to /home/username/? Can you try to cv::imwrite to that folder? Do you see no mp4 file at all or do you see a tiny file without frames?